# Getting audio src atribute with JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to access the src atribute of the mp3 file inside the second "section" element. How do I do that with JQuery?

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="slides">
    <section>
        <h3 class="audio"><audio src="file.mp3" /></h3>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h3 class="audio"><audio src="otherfile.mp3" /></h3>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h3 class="audio"><audio src="audio.mp3" /></h3>
    </section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

I think this should be of help to you. :)

The code would be `jQuery('audio:eq(1)').attr('src');`

Comment: I was trying: `$('audio').get(1).attr('src');` and `$('section')[1].('audio').attr('src');` but with no success. The way you showed worked though; thanks.

Comment: @Roger The problem with that, is that the `attr` method is applied to the array. `get` returns just the element, which won't have the method. Same for the second snippet. The reason mine works, is because it still returns an array. :)

Comment: This works also: `alert($('section:eq(1) audio').attr('src'));`

Comment: @roger Yup. What browser are you using? I'm using Chrome 10 beta for Mac.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to assign an id to the source element:

```
 <audio controls="controls">
      <source id="src1" src="/Tools/LoadAudioWav/@ViewBag.FilePath" type="audio/ogg" />
      <source id="src2"src="/Tools/LoadAudioMp3/@ViewBag.FilePath" type="audio/mpeg" />
 </audio>
```

Then from Jquery

```
    var p2 = document.getElementById('src1'); 

    var source = p2.src; //to get the value

    p2.src = "/Tools/LoadAudio?id=aud3"  // to assign a value
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, normally you'd have `id`s for specific elements you want to access.

However, you can still do what you want:

```
var source = $('#slides section:nth-child(2) audio').attr('src');
```

See [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/).